# How to control visibility of mapbox markers with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

On my website I have a toggle menu that allows a user to filter search results on a map based on whatever category they select.

My current problem is that I'm using a jQuery function to control the "select all" and "clear" functions on this list, and while the menu works fine, it doesnt change the visibility of the elements on the map.

Is there any way to reference a function that I was already using with javascript within my jQuery?

```js
var reset = document.getElementsByClassName("reset");
var selectall = document.getElementsByClassName("selectall");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "checkbox";
input.id = layerID;

$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
div.appendChild(input);

var label = document.createElement("label");
label.setAttribute("for", layerID);
label.textContent = categories;
div.appendChild(label);
filterGroup.appendChild(div);

input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  map.setLayoutProperty(
    layerID,
    "visibility",
    e.target.checked ? "visible" : "none"
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reset").click(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectall").click(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems that the results from first two lines: `var reset = document.getElementsByClassName("reset");
var selectall = document.getElementsByClassName("selectall");` are never used.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was using a bunch of different functions that I found off of the internet to see which one would work the best, and as a result of that I have those two lines left over. I was trying to see if I could have a jquery function that toggles the menu selection on and off while simultaneously having a javascript function that controls how the items populate on my map